# Swift / How to parse json from java spring code

Tags: sql, swift, spring

I want to parse json from java spring code (Xcode 7.3 / Swift). I tried almost every solution from all sites.

When I register it gives the following error message at the console:

```
Response = Optional(<NSHTTPURLResponse: 0x7a7607e0> { URL: http://www.____.com/saveRegistrationJson.htm } { status code: 405, headers {
    Allow = GET;
    Connection = "Keep-Alive";
    "Content-Length" = 1089;
    "Content-Type" = "text/html;charset=utf-8";
    Date = "Wed, 04 May 2016 12:21:34 GMT";
    "Keep-Alive" = "timeout=15, max=100";
    Server = "Apache-Coyote/1.1";
} })
before json
Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840 "Invalid value around character 0." UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=Invalid value around character 0.}
```

This is my Code:

```
import UIKit

class RegistrationViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var userfnametextfield: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var userlnametextfield: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var useremailtextfield: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var userpwdtextfield: UITextField!


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@IBAction func RegisterbtnTapped(sender: AnyObject) {

    let fname = userfnametextfield.text
    let lname = userlnametextfield.text
    let Email = useremailtextfield.text
    let pwd = userpwdtextfield.text

    //check empty fields
    if(fname!.isEmpty || lname!.isEmpty || Email!.isEmpty || pwd!.isEmpty )
  {
        DisplayMyAlertMessage("All Fields are required")
        return
    }

    //store data
    NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(fname, forKey: "fname")

    NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(lname, forKey: "lname")

    NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(Email, forKey: "Email")

    NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(pwd, forKey: "password")

    NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().synchronize()


    //send user data to server side
    let myurl = NSURL(string: "http://www.____.com/saveRegistrationJson.htm")
    let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: myurl!)

    request.HTTPMethod = "POST"
    let poststring = "fname\(fname!)&lname\(lname!)&email\(Email!)&password\(pwd!)"

   request.HTTPBody = poststring.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)
    //request.HTTPBody = postData

    let task = NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithRequest(request){data,response, error in

        if error != nil{
            print("Error\(error)")
            return
        }
        print("Response = \(response)")

        do{

            var err : NSError?
           print("before json")
        let json = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.AllowFragments) as? NSDictionary

            print(json)
            print("After json")
            //print("demo : \(response?.description)")

            guard let parseJSON = json else{
                print("parsing json here:")
                return
            }
           // guard let value = NSString(data: data!, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding) else{
             //   print("parsed")
               // return
            //}
            //print("FirstName\(value)")

                var requestValue = parseJSON[" "] as? String
                print("result:\(requestValue)")

                var isUserRegistered:Bool = false
                if(requestValue=="Success") { isUserRegistered = true}

                var messageToDisplay:String = parseJSON["Success"] as! String
                if(!isUserRegistered){
                    messageToDisplay = parseJSON[" "] as! String
                }


                dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
                    let myAlert = UIAlertController(title: "Alert", message: messageToDisplay, preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)


                    let onAction = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default) { (ACTION) -> Void in

                        self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
                    }
                    myAlert.addAction(onAction)
                    self.presentViewController(myAlert, animated: true, completion: nil)


                })

            }

        catch let error as NSError
        {
            print(error)
        }
    }

    task.resume()
```

Help is very appreciated.

Comment: The error message is rather straightforward: "Invalid value around character 0." It means the JSON from the server is invalid, the first character is not a valid character for JSON, it's not a `[` or a `{` as it should be. This is an issue *on the server side*.

Comment: Could you give us a print out of what the JSON was received by the client (as a string, before parsing)

Comment: when i put the url to save registration on a browser with all values it returns Success on a page. It means when user is registered it returning a string.

Comment: http://www.___.com/saveRegistrationJson.htm?fname=dipali&lname=pawshe&email=mm@nn.com&password=1111   This shows a string called "Success"

Comment: can some1 please help me to tell how to parse a string sent from server